# Google apps script: loop over tabs to save to separate worksheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to loop over all individual tabs of a certain worksheet (preferably skipping the ones of array that need to be excluded). For each individual tab I would like to save it as a separate worksheet in Google drive, with the title of the tab as the file name. If the file name already exists it should be overwritten.

Preferably I would like to be able to exclude an array of sheets (e.g. named 'master' and 'test') in the desired script.

Unfortunately my knowledge of Google Apps scripting is not sufficient enough to write it myself. Any working example is highly appreciated.

EDIT: here is how I solved it (suggestions for improvements are always welcome! :-) )
EDIT2: changed the deleteSheet line

```
function copySheetsToSS() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  for(var n in ss.getSheets()){// loop over all tabs in the spreadsheet
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[n];// look at every sheet in spreadsheet
    var name = sheet.getName();//get name
    if(name != 'master' && name != 'test'){ // exclude some names
      var alreadyExist = DriveApp.getFilesByName(name);// check if already there
      while(alreadyExist.hasNext()){
        alreadyExist.next().setTrashed(true);// delete all files with this name
      }
      var copy = SpreadsheetApp.create(name);// create the copy
      sheet.copyTo(copy).setName(name); // rename copied sheet to same name as SS
      copy.deleteSheet(copy.getSheets()[0]);// delete default Sheet1 from new copy
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 2 comments about the last part of your code you just added (without mentioning the source of the first part) : `sheet.copyTo(copy).setName(name)` will fail if your source has a sheet called `Sheet1` (error =sheet with this name already exist) and 2 : `deleteActiveSheet()[0]` is not a valid method, the `[0]` parameter does not exist and has no effect... this method deletes the active sheet (which is by default `sheet[0]` in a newly created sheet).  All in All, I would suggest you use my (edited) version below which is safer and works in every circumstances.

Comment: OK, but there is still an issue if the source spreadsheet has a sheet called sheet1 .

Comment: Yes, I'm willing to take the risk that the source will not have a sheet called Sheet1.... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your description is so accurate that it's quite easy to translate in code...

You should have tried and I'm sure the doc would have allowed you to get it working ... it would have been interesting and so rewarding to run a code you wrote yourself !

Here is the more frustrating (for you) solution of a working code ;-) with explanation in comments

```
function copySheetsToSS() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  for(var n in ss.getSheets()){
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[n];// look at every sheet in spreadsheet
    var name = sheet.getName();//get name
    if(name != 'master' && name != 'test'){ // exclude some names
      var alreadyExist = DriveApp.getFilesByName(name);// check if already there
      while(alreadyExist.hasNext()){
        alreadyExist.next().setTrashed(true);// delete all files with this name
      }
      var copy = SpreadsheetApp.create(name);// create the copy
      sheet.copyTo(copy);// copy content
      copy.deleteSheet(copy.getSheets()[0]);// remove original "Sheet1"
      copy.getSheets()[0].setName(name);// rename first sheet to same name as SS
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wonderful; works like a charm. Except that I noticed my exceptions were not put in an array... lol! Thank you so much, Serge!

Comment: Oops; I cheered too soon! The new worksheets are created properly; but the contents of each individual tab is not copied over somehow. So this function ends up creating new spreadsheets with proper names, but with all blank cells.

Comment: you're right...;-) I forgot the part to copy content!! sorry about that, code updated, see edit.(Ooooooops...:-)

Comment: Hmmm didn't see you completed the code yourself... sorry for being late on this one :-)  the good point is that we came to almost the same code! Except your delete sheet which I'm not sure is a good choice.